# Group Maker Algorithm based on free time avaliable

Tags: algorithm, date

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that would make groups based on the maximum free time available a group of people have in polynomial time, but I believe the solution to this problem might be NP.

**The problem is as followed:**

We divided the week into 1 hour slots where users can put down for each slot whether they are free or busy. Let's say we gather this information from 30 users. Let's also assume that users%group_size = 0

**First:**

Is it possible to put these people into groups of size G so that every member in each group of size G has one overlapping free time slot with each other?

Is it possible to put these people into groups of size G that results in an optimal solution, which is to have the maximum total overlapping free time slots among all groups?

For example, if we had a group of 6 people with the following free time:

A: 1pm-3pm Sunday AND 1pm-3pm Monday

B: 2pm-3pm Sunday AND 1pm-3pm Monday

C: 1pm-3pm Sunday AND 7pm-9pm Monday

D: 6pm-7pm Sunday AND 7pm-9pm Monday

E: 5pm-7pm Sunday AND 7pm-9pm Monday

F: 6pm-7pm Sunday AND 1pm-3pm Monday

The algorithm would determine that A,B,F would be one group and C,D,E would be another group because a maximum of two hours of free time overlaps between the groups. This is opposed to A,B,C and D,E,F which only contains 1 overlapping time slot for every member in the group. As a result, this is optimal solution which is greatest overlap in total among all groups.

I realized this problem is probably related to the Hopcroft-Karp Algorithm, but needs to be modified greatly to accomplish this task. Is their another algorithm that relates more closely to the solution then the Hopcroft-Karp Algorithm? Can this solution be achieved in polynomial time?

**Background:**

We have a bunch of people(30-50) who want to volunteer for a cause and they only have certain times they are free during the week. We want to break them into groups of 3-5 and have them work together for this cause. We want the group members to have as much time as possible with each other so we want to break them into groups where they have similar free times available.

Thanks a bunch and please let me know if this is an obvious question or if more clarification is needed.

Comment: This is a very attractive question, but do you think it would be better asked on MathOverflow?  Then you could use the answer there to ask an implementation-specific question here.  Note; I do know that no all SO questions are about implementations.

Comment: I never heard of MathOverflow. I will check it out and put it up there too. Thanks!

Comment: Does the stated question "Is it possible to put these people into groups of size G so that every member in each group of size G has one overlapping free time slot with each other?" mean that all members of the group need to have the same free timeslot? This would make more sense i guess, but when I first read your question, it sounded like a pairwise overlapping of time slots would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, All members of the group need to have the same free timeslot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first look, it seems like a set cover problem, where a subset is number of persons sharing a time slot and the universal set would be all the persons.

```
U = {p0, p1, p2 ..... , p29}  // Number of persons.
S = {S0, S1, S2, ....... S23} // number of 1 hour slots.
```

I am still not sure how to use the G(size of a ideal group) into account.